# Cross-Section Analysis

Tags: regression, cross-section

I have cross-section individual data and   would like to regress individuals' 2011 wages (in logarithm) on the region-varying minimum wage (MW).

The MW variable will be subject to endogeneity (e.g. omitted variable bias, etc.) and I will use OLS IV approach as the identification strategy.

I have multiple observations for the local MW but only the 2011 observation on individual wages.  My question is what is the difference in terms of benefits/costs and interpretation in the respective coefficients if I were to use the real MW level in 2010 versus using the change in the MW from the 2004-2010 period (i.e. first-differencing).

Any direct answer or text recommendation is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By no means an expert at this, but I don't think there is any benefit in using the change in the minimum wage when your dependent variable is cross-sectional. You would still face the same problem of potential endogeneity. Furthermore, I don't see how the relative change in a variable would be an appropriate choice when trying to predict the level of an outcome variable.